# R: for loop output save only last results in output dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following for loop script:

```
# Create example data
dataKM <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5,    
                     x2 = 6:10,
                     x3 = 11:15)
# Duplicate dataframe
datatest <- dataKM[c(1:3)]

# for loop
for(i in colnames(dataKM[,2:ncol(dataKM)])) {
  # median of each single column of dataframe
  median <- median(dataKM[,i])
  # add column in duplicated dataframe with 'High' or 'low' based on median for each column
  datatest$median[dataKM[,i] <= median ] <- "Low"
  datatest$median[dataKM[,i] > median ] <- "High"
}
```

I'm trying to repeat for loop for each column of dataKM dataframe and save results as column in dataset dataframe. My script save only the last iteration. Probably I get a single output because I overwrite the previous value on each pass in the loop.
I'd like to know how I can save all for loop output in their respective column.
Can anyone help me? Thank you so much, I hope this can be useful even for someone else trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is compared with what. But here is an example were x2 value or x3 value is compared with its column median:

Here is a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)

dataKM %>% 
  mutate(across(-1, ~case_when(. <= median(., na.rm=TRUE) ~ "Low",
                               . > median(., nar.rm=TRUE) ~ "High"), .names = "Median_{.col}"))
```

```
  x1 x2 x3 Median_x2 Median_x3
1  1  6 11       Low       Low
2  2  7 12       Low       Low
3  3  8 13       Low       Low
4  4  9 14      High      High
5  5 10 15      High      High
```

Comment: Your dplyr approach is exactly what I need for my analysis. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: And may I ask, why you then unaccepted the answer? It is ok for me just wondering?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally took it off

Answer (score 2):

We can just use `lapply` function

```
datatest <- dataKM[c(2:3)]
datatest[] <- lapply(dataKM[-1] , function(x) ifelse(x <= median(x) , "Low" , "High"))

colnames(datatest) <- c("x2Median" , "x3Median")

cbind(dataKM , datatest)
```

- output

```
  x1 x2 x3  x2Median x3Median
1  1  6 11      Low      Low
2  2  7 12      Low      Low
3  3  8 13      Low      Low
4  4  9 14      High     High
5  5 10 15      High     High
```

**If you insist using `for loop`  try this**

```
datatest <- dataKM[c(1:3)]

for(i in colnames(dataKM[-1])) {
    median <- median(dataKM[,i])
    datatest[[paste0(i,"median")]][dataKM[,i] <= median ] <- "Low"
    datatest[[paste0(i,"median")]][dataKM[,i] > median ] <- "High"
}
```

Comment: First column column also?

Comment: I think OP said "for loop for each column of dataKM dataframe" !

Comment: I think, colnames(dataKM[,2:ncol(dataKM)]) means 2 to last column!

Comment: Yes, colnames (dataKM [, 2: ncol (dataKM)]) means 2 up to the last column. The first column in my real dataset is a numeric column, but I don't need to calculate the median of it.

Comment: The dplyr approach is @TarJae solution , pls add this comment after his solution .

Comment: Thank you Mohamed for your help. Your first solution produce this error: unexpected input in "datatest[] <- lapply(dataKM, \"; the second one is what i want.

Comment: Updated , i think you have an old version of `R` < 4.1.0 .

Comment: Yes, I'm working on R 4.0.4. Thank you for update.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are updating a single new column, *median*. Simply adjust to create new median column with each iteration of `for` loop, concatenating the column current column name and *median*.

```r
# for loop
for(col in colnames(dataKM[,2:ncol(dataKM)])) {
  curr_col <- dataKM[[col]]
  # median of each single column of dataframe
  col_median <- median(curr_col)

  # add column in duplicated dataframe with 'High' or 'low' based on median for each column
  datatest[[paste0(col, "_median")]][curr_col <= col_median] <- "Low"
  datatest[[paste0(col, "_median")]][curr_col > col_median] <- "High"
}
```

Alternatively, with `ifelse`:

```r
for(col in colnames(dataKM[,2:ncol(dataKM)])) {
  curr_col <- dataKM[[col]]
  col_median <- median(curr_col)

  datatest[[paste0(col, "_median")]] <- ifelse(
    curr_col <= col_median, "Low", " High"
  )
}
```